# 502 Bad Gateway The server returned an invalid or incomplete response

Tags: html

i have uploaded my static web site on my hosting.
i have set the video to Carousel's background which would be approx 25mb in size 
Doesn't Loads videos
it failed to load by showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)" in inspect console 
by opening video by path in another tab it shows me the error "502 Bad Gateway
The server returned an invalid or incomplete response."
checkout Below Code

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>How the us taxation works</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">LEARN MORE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       <span class="text-uppercase">Local, State</span>
       <h1>or Federal Taxes</h1>
       <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get In Touch</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-trans">Learn more</button>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="item">
     <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop>
  <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Featured projects showcase</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get In Touch</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
```

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gijbs.png)
[Opening video in browser by path shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUSAE.png)

Comment: Check [here](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939) or [here](https://www.godaddy.com/community/GoCentral-Website-Builder/502-Bad-Gateway-error-when-adding-a-new-page-to-my-blog/td-p/3779). This will give you more detailed information. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A **502 Bad Gateway error** is not caused by static HTML/bootstrap like you just displayed.

The server was probably having an internal error or an error communicating with other servers - maybe there was a (temporary) overload, or another server/service was not reachable. Does it still happen when you clear your cache or use another browser/computer?
Potential steps to fix:

- Look for server connectivity issues.
- Check for any DNS changes.
- Sift through your logs.
- Fix faulty firewall configurations.
- Comb through your website’s code to find bugs.

Link that might help you: [Link](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/502-bad-gateway).

Comment: As I put the site on the subdomain other sites working fine as suggested I run it on different browser also but the same result. also tested on my machine local apache server no works fine no code issue

Answer (score 0):

Error 502s are not caused by your code, 5xx errors are caused by an error in the server. Try clearing your cache, checking the server (if you can), and waiting.

Comment: waited for 2 days and tried on different browser and machines but doesn't work

Comment: try contacting your host, and maybe show us the link to your site